# ¿Cómo obtener registros de un intervalo de días en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos a todos, tengo una tabla con 1 campo de *fecha*. Necesito obtener, para imprimir, los registros que tengan caducidad 5 días antes del dato almacenado en el campo *fecha*.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
SELECT fecha, datediff(now(),ret) FROM tabla
```

***fecha*** es el campo y ***now()*** es la fecha actual

Comment: ¿Qué formato de fecha se guarda en el campo que tienes?

Comment: No se entiende bien el problema.

¿Para qué necesitas now()? En el problema planteas que quieres los registros en los que su fecha "ret" caduquen 5 días antes que "fecha1", no del día actual.

Comment: El campo es tipo date Y-m-d orici

Comment: Hola alberto, por eso estoy algo perdido, quiero que me imprima solo los registros de ret donde segun la fecha actual sea 5 dias antes de ret

Answer (score -1):

Resolví el problema de esta manera

```
SELECT ret from caso WHERE datediff(ret,now()) = -55
```